# when I click on the "Generate" button work just once time

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my button when for example I click on button StartGame "try again" and I play after that the generate button doesn't work.

I think that this problem happens because the button is inside the oncreate method before the other code

```java
package com.forfree.com.robux;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Frame
    private FrameLayout gameFrame;
    private int frameHeight, frameWidth, initialFrameWidth;
    private LinearLayout startLayout;
    Button generate;

    // Image
    private ImageView box, black, orange, pink;
    private Drawable imageBoxRight, imageBoxLeft;

    // Size
    private int boxSize;

    // Position
    private float boxX, boxY;
    private float blackX, blackY;
    private float orangeX, orangeY;
    private float pinkX, pinkY;

    // Score
    private TextView scoreLabel, highScoreLabel;
    private int score, highScore, timeCount;
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    // Class
    private Timer timer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SoundPlayer soundPlayer;

    // Status
    private boolean start_flg = false;
    private boolean action_flg = false;
    private boolean pink_flg = false;
    private static float width;
    int progressState = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////// THIS IS MY BUTTON THAT WORK ONCE THIME

            generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
            generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    showProgressDialog();
                }
            });
        }

        public void showProgressDialog(){
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Congrats you win "+score+" Robux");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);


            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setProgress(0);
            pDialog.setMax(100);


            pDialog.show();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while( progressState < 100 ){

                        progressState += 10;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        pDialog.setProgress(progressState);

                    }

                    if (progressState>= 100)
                        pDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }).start();


            ////////

        soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(this);

        gameFrame = findViewById(R.id.gameFrame);
        startLayout = findViewById(R.id.startLayout);
        box = findViewById(R.id.box);
        black = findViewById(R.id.black);
        orange = findViewById(R.id.orange);
        pink = findViewById(R.id.pink);
        scoreLabel = findViewById(R.id.scoreLabel);
        highScoreLabel = findViewById(R.id.highScoreLabel);

        imageBoxLeft = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.box_left);
        imageBoxRight = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.box_right);

        // High Score
        settings = getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        highScore = settings.getInt("HIGH_SCORE", 0);
        highScoreLabel.setText("High Score : " + highScore);
    }

    //

    //

    public void changePos() {

        // Add timeCount
        timeCount += 20;

        // Orange
        orangeY += 12;

        float orangeCenterX = orangeX + orange.getWidth() / 2;
        float orangeCenterY = orangeY + orange.getHeight() / 2;

        if (hitCheck(orangeCenterX, orangeCenterY)) {
            orangeY = frameHeight + 100;
            score += 233;
            soundPlayer.playHitOrangeSound();
        }

        if (orangeY > frameHeight) {
            orangeY = -100;
            orangeX = (float) Math.floor(Math.random() * (frameWidth - orange.getWidth()));
        }
        orange.setX(orangeX);
        orange.setY(orangeY);

        // Pink
        if (!pink_flg && timeCount % 10000 == 0) {
            pink_flg = true;
            pinkY = -20;
            pinkX = (float) Math.floor(Math.random() * (frameWidth - pink.getWidth()));
        }

        if (pink_flg) {
            pinkY += 20;

            float pinkCenterX = pinkX + pink.getWidth() / 2;
            float pinkCenterY = pinkY + pink.getWidth() / 2;

            if (hitCheck(pinkCenterX, pinkCenterY)) {
                pinkY = frameHeight + 30;
                score += 30;
                // Change FrameWidth
                if (initialFrameWidth > frameWidth * 110 / 100) {
                    frameWidth = frameWidth * 110 / 100;
                    changeFrameWidth(frameWidth);
                }
                soundPlayer.playHitPinkSound();
            }

            if (pinkY > frameHeight) pink_flg = false;
            pink.setX(pinkX);
            pink.setY(pinkY);
        }

        // Black
        blackY += 18;

        float blackCenterX = blackX + black.getWidth() / 2;
        float blackCenterY = blackY + black.getHeight() / 2;

        if (hitCheck(blackCenterX, blackCenterY)) {
            blackY = frameHeight + 100;

            // Change FrameWidth
            frameWidth = frameWidth * 80 / 100;
            changeFrameWidth(frameWidth);
            soundPlayer.playHitBlackSound();
            if (frameWidth <= boxSize) {
                gameOver();
            }

        }

        if (blackY > frameHeight) {
            blackY = -100;
            blackX = (float) Math.floor(Math.random() * (frameWidth - black.getWidth()));
        }

        black.setX(blackX);
        black.setY(blackY);

        // Move Box
        if (action_flg) {
            // Touching
            boxX += 14;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBoxRight);
        } else {
            // Releasing
            boxX -= 14;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBoxLeft);
        }

        // Check box position.
        if (boxX < 0) {
            boxX = 0;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBoxRight);
        }
        if (frameWidth - boxSize < boxX) {
            boxX = frameWidth - boxSize;
            box.setImageDrawable(imageBoxLeft);
        }

        box.setX(boxX);

        scoreLabel.setText(" Robux Collected : " + score);

    }

    //


    //

    public boolean hitCheck(float x, float y) {
        if (boxX <= x && x <= boxX + boxSize &&
                boxY <= y && y <= frameHeight) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void changeFrameWidth(int frameWidth) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gameFrame.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = frameWidth;
        gameFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        // Stop timer.
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
        start_flg = false;

        // Before showing startLayout, sleep 1 second.
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        changeFrameWidth(initialFrameWidth);

        startLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        box.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        black.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        orange.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Update High Score
        if (score > highScore) {
            highScore = score;
            highScoreLabel.setText("Robux Getting : " + highScore);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("HIGH_SCORE", highScore);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (start_flg) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                action_flg = true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                action_flg = false;

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void startGame(View view) {
        start_flg = true;
        startLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (frameHeight == 0) {
            frameHeight = gameFrame.getHeight();
            frameWidth = gameFrame.getWidth();
            initialFrameWidth = frameWidth;

            boxSize = box.getHeight();
            boxX = box.getX();
            boxY = box.getY();
        }

        frameWidth = initialFrameWidth;

        box.setX(0.0f);
        black.setY(3000.0f);
        orange.setY(3000.0f);
        pink.setY(3000.0f);

        blackY = black.getY();
        orangeY = orange.getY();
        pinkY = pink.getY();

        box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        black.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        orange.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pink.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        timeCount = 0;
        score = 0;
        scoreLabel.setText("Score : 0");


        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (start_flg) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            changePos();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, 0, 20);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, when you click the button first, the `progressState` counts up to 100 and dismisses the dialog.
Every time you click the button again, `progressState` still remains at 100 or more.

Reset the `progressState` in the onClick method of the button.

It should look like this:

```
generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
        generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                progressState = 0;
                showProgressDialog();
            }
        });
```